# Drop reads and drop mutations in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have large Cassandra cluster with multiple DC. Sometimes I am getting INFO message for Drop read and drop mutations in debug.log with 213 internal and 514 cross node. however, application was not impacted. As per my understanding actual request was not failing but some of the replica did not respond to the coordinator and if consistency achieved then request got successful. please clarify if I am having misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The application will not get an error from the coordinator if the consistency level for the requests are satisfied. You mentioned that the application was not impacted but that's likely because:

- the read or write request has a low consistency level (for example, `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE`), or
- the request consistency level is `LOCAL_*` but failed for a replica(s) in a remote DC.

FWIW, internal dropped messages is when the local node rejected the read or write request and cross-node is for requests to remote nodes (replicas). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @flightc for your reply so we can ignore those drop read and drop mutations until app is not impacted?

Comment: Usually it's still recommended to investigate why this happens - this is a first sign that nodes are overloaded...

Comment: Yes Alex, we found some slow queries also which were taking time more than threshold value during the issue time. Can it be a reason?