# READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 2 internal and 0 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 2556 ms

Tags: cassandra

application reading the queries using go-lang drivers.
the query like select * from tab1 where id=123 and datehr='12-10-2019';

each partition have 36k rows.
each row size is 120 bytes.
each partition size is 4MB.

But i am getting information in Cassandra debug logs like below. and also application getting read timeout issues. and application go-lang driver using fetch size is 5000.

cassandra version is 3.11.4
java-version java version "1.8.0_131"
OS version: centos 7.3
Cpu cores: 16
RAM: 64GB
HEAP: 16/16

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:45:32,095 MessagingService.java:1236 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 2 internal and 4 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 3449 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 3621 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:45:32,129 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:46:52,135 MessagingService.java:1236 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 1 internal and 0 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 2922 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 3449 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:46:52,147 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:51:32,157 MessagingService.java:1236 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 2 internal and 0 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 2556 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 0 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:51:32,166 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:52:47,169 MessagingService.java:1236 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 2 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 1270 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-01-20 13:52:47,179 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Could you please clarify exactly what the problem is and how we can help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think, same thing explained here regarding drop mutations and read mutations. please refer below
[Drop reads and drop mutations in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403223/drop-reads-and-drop-mutations-in-cassandra)